# Change data type of an interface

Tags: go, interface

I'm trying to determine what data type a passed in interface is
and then assign declare a new object with that data type. Here's the example:

```
func SomeFunction(ctx context.Context, records interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
        type objType = CustomStruct0
    
        switch v := records.(type) {
        case CustomStruct1:
            fmt.Println("-----CustomStruct1-------")
            objType = CustomStruct1
        case CustomStruct2:
            fmt.Println("-----CustomStruct2-------")
            objType = CustomStruct2
        case CustomStruct3:
            fmt.Println("-----CustomStruct3-------")
            objType = CustomStruct3
        default:
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("data type not recognized")
        }

    recordsNew = i.(objType)
    fmt.Println("records in recordsNew:", recordsNew)
```

However the error is I get is the following: type CustomStruct1 is not an expression.
As suggested the records object can be one one those 4 interfaces/structs.
Any guidance/pointers will be much appreciated.

What I'm trying to achieve, is the following

SomeFunction() gets called from 4 different places.
where the records object is set to 4 different structs.
Simple solution is to have 4 SomeFunctions() accepting the exact dataType from the caller.
But I'm just attempting to combine all that into one
and determine what the dataType is of the passed in interfac, based on which, I can initialize the new object and fetch the properties I need from those structs down eblow.

I understand setting this
`objType = CustomStruct1`
isn't correct, b ut I'm hoping there's a way
to set ObjType to a default type outside of the switch block,
and then re-initalize ObjType based on the datatype records interface is.

Comment: like the error says, types are not an expression, and cannot be assigned, and since the `recordsNew` type must be known at compile time, you couldn't "asssign" a type at runtime anyway.  The `v` value is already asserted to the type you want however, what can't you do within the switch statement?

Comment: I think the error is "`CustomStruct0` is not an expression", correct? As you are trying to create a new variable with `CustomStruct0` here: `type objType = CustomStruct0`

Comment: Thank you, kind folks.. I updated the description of the problem and hopefully that clarifies the picture a  abit.

Comment: @user6304988 The higher-level goal is still not clear (at least to me).  Perhaps it will help to show the code for one of the types.

Comment: Perhaps you should improve `records interface{}` to a more descriptive interface that actually captures the behaviour of a "record", then you don't need to mess around with switches.  That's what interfaces are for.  See the link at [go proverbs](https://go-proverbs.github.io/), `interface{}` says nothing.

Comment: you just put your specific logics into the swtich case statements. no ?

Comment: @mh-cbon good point, but the logic is over 500 lines of code, so it will be somewhat redundant. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco thanks for sharing the proverbs. They are truly handy.

Comment: either you know upfront the properties you need to fetch, and they are shared, so you declare some var before, type switch the object to assign those variables and consume them later, either you add more type switch along the big chunk of code, wherever needed, or, you can refactor those types to make use of interfaces (i dont mean empty interfaces). You can also get the type as a string value and switch over that, but it is the same as a regular type switch.

Answer (score 1):

Follow is my approach, using "reflect" library from go lang office, just solve the problem when you want to check the type of your variable:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type CustomStruct1 struct {
}

type CustomStruct2 struct {
}

type CustomStruct3 struct {
}

func main() {
    var customStruct1 CustomStruct1
    SomeFunction(customStruct1)
}

func SomeFunction(records interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    switch fmt.Sprintf("%s", reflect.TypeOf(records)) {
    case "main.CustomStruct1":
        fmt.Println("-----CustomStruct1-------")
    case "main.CustomStruct2":
        fmt.Println("-----CustomStruct2-------")
    case "main.CustomStruct3":
        fmt.Println("-----CustomStruct3-------")
    default:
        fmt.Println("-----Unrecognized Struct-------")
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("data type not recognized")
    }

    return records, nil
}
==========
$ go run main.go
-----CustomStruct1-------
```

Comment: thank you for the response, but that doesn't really answer my question. Your answer does give what type the records interface is, but that wasn't the question. Thank you however for attempting to respond. 
But just to go off of your suggestion, this is is what I want:
in main
recordsType = someFunction(customStruct)
recordsNew = records.(recordsType)

fmt.Println("name", recordsNew.Name)